# Additional property port is not allowed in docker compose

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, yaml

I am trying to run my docker-compose.yaml file on aws ec2 instance but I keep getting this error

```
services.postgres Additional property port is not allowed
```

My YAML file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    java-maven-app:
        image: oshabz/docker-demo:1.1.0-25
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    postgres:
        image: postgres:13
        port:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my-pwd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the property `ports` not `port` - as you have done with the `java-maven-app` service.  So your postgres service should look like (use `ports` not `port`)

```
    postgres:
        image: postgres:13
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my-pwd
```